# Script php sem permissão em documento root

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

Gostaria de criar um *log* com informações de visitantes da pagina, mas o script não tem permissão de escrita.

Como proceder?

> PHP Warning:  fopen(log.txt): failed to open stream: Permiss\xc3\xa3o
>   negada in /var/www/html/index.php on line 30

Comment: Ja havia tentado e tentei novamente mas sem sucesso.. PHP Warning:  fopen(/home/user/Docs/webpage/log.txt): failed to open stream: Permiss\xc3\xa3o negada in /var/www/html/index.php on line 30

Comment: Tente o seguinte: abra um terminal e navegue até a pasta onde se encontra o arquivo `log.txt`, então digite: `sudo chmod 777 log.txt`, assim você vai mudar as permissões de acesso a esse arquivo.

Comment: Obrigado! @QMechanic73 :)

Comment: Posso postar uma resposta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talvez seja necessário alterar as permissões de acesso. Abra um terminal e navegue até o local onde se encontra o arquivo, e digite:

```
sudo chmod 777 log.txt
```

Isso vai permitir a você o acesso total sobre esse arquivo. Para mais informações sobre o uso do `chmod` pode ser visto [**aqui**](http://www.uniriotec.br/~morganna/guia/chmod.html).